# how to change the source of an image dynamically in HTML?

Tags: html

Please help me with this question I am trying to change the source of an image dynamically.

Comment: HTML can't do it alone. What do you want to change it in response to? What language? Client side or server side?

Comment: No problem. But it is entirely unclear from your question where exactly you're stucking? What do you have as far? What happens? What happens not? Please read this how to ask a good question: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Client-side (Dynamic) Image-Swapping...

You'll need to use javascript for this:

`<img src="image1.jpg" id="myImage" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = "image2.jpg";
</script>
```

#### Introducing jQuery...

If this is the type of response you are looking for, then I would also like to extend an invitation to you to start checking out and javascript framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), which makes this type of stuff much easier to do/manage. In jQuery, you can accomplish the same thing with the following code:

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", "image2.jpg");
```

Comment: Or any server side language: src="[% myimage %]". Depending on what "dynamic" means in context.

Comment: Correct. With the context of "html," I thought it was safe to assume he was speaking of client-side "dynamic," but the question is indeed equivocal.